# For any sequence $\{a_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ such that $\lim \frac {a_{n_{k+1}}}{a_{n_k}}$ exists and belongs to $\{0, 1,∞\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of non-zero real numbers. Show that it has a
subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ such that $\lim \frac {a_{n_{k+1}}}{a_{n_k}}$
exists and belongs to $\{0, 1,∞\}$.
If we consider the sequence $\{n\}$ and the  subsequence $\{n\}$ itself then $\lim \frac {a_{n_{k+1}}}{a_{n_k}}=1.$ I am not able to prove the above in general.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: hint: you can suppose the terms are positive, set $b_n=\log a_n$, now the sequence $b_n$ is either unbounded from below, or from above, or bounded - in the last case you have a convergent subsequence, giving the result 1, the other two cases can give you either $0$ or $\infty$

Answer (score 2):

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a real sequence, such that $a_n\neq0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We consider four cases:

- $(a_n)_n$ admits a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ such that $a_{n_k}\stackrel{k\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}0$,
- $(a_n)_n$ admits a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ such that $a_{n_k}\stackrel{k\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}a\neq0$,
- $(a_n)_n$ admits a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ such that $a_{n_k}\stackrel{k\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}\infty$,
- $(a_n)_n$ admits a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ such that $a_{n_k}\stackrel{k\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}-\infty$.

That at least one of these cases occurs is a consequence of the Bolzano-Weierstraß Theorem.

*Case 1:* Fix a sequence $\left(h_l\right)_l$ such that $h_l>0$ for all $l\in\mathbb{N}$ and $h_l\stackrel{l\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}0$. We construct a subsequence $\left(a_{n_{k_l}}\right)_l$ as follows: Let $k_1\colon=1$ and then pick $k_{l+1}$ inductively such that $\left\lvert a_{n_{k_{l+1}}}\right\rvert<h_l\left\lvert a_{n_{k_l}}\right\rvert$. Then
$$0\le\left\lvert\frac{a_{n_{k_{l+1}}}}{a_{n_{k_l}}}\right\rvert<h_l\stackrel{l\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}0,\text{ hence }\frac{a_{n_{k_{l+1}}}}{a_{n_{k_l}}}\stackrel{l\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}0.$$

*Case 2:* In this case, trivially $\frac{a_{n_{k+1}}}{a_{n_k}}\stackrel{k\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}\frac{a}{a}=1$.

*Case 3:* Fix a sequence $(h_l)_l$ such that $h_l\stackrel{l\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}\infty$. We construct a subsequence $\left(a_{n_{k_l}}\right)_l$ as follows: Let $k_1\colon=1$ and then pick $k_{l+1}$ inductively, such that $a_{n_{k_{l+1}}}>h_la_{n_{k_l}}$. Then
$$\frac{a_{n_{k_{l+1}}}}{a_{n_{k_l}}}>h_l\stackrel{l\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}\infty.$$

*Case 4:* Apply the case 3 argument to $\left(|a_{n_k}|\right)_k$ and notice that $\left\lvert\frac{a_{n_{k+1}}}{a_{n_k}}\right\rvert=\frac{a_{n_{k+1}}}{a_{n_k}}$ for sufficiently large $k$ as the sequence $\left(a_{n_k}\right)_k$ will be negative for sufficiently large $k$.